# How to center the tag for a multiline diagram?

Tags: equations, numbering, vertical-alignment

I have a diagram, say five lines, the tag (equation numbering) is in the first line, this is not I want. How to force the tag stay in the middle line? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the `amsmath` package, which provides an `aligned` environment:

```
\begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned}
    \Sigma &= a + b + c + d\\
           & + e + f + g + h\\
           & + i + j + k + l
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: In the same package there's also `gathered` which doesn't use the & sign for alignment -- depending on your equation this may be of more use to you.

Comment: And `split` is preferred to `aligned`.

Comment: As a I say diagram (an xymatrix), it is a one-line object occupied many lines. I want the tag is in the center line and the ","(as suggested) is in the last line.